# Enable CORS origin graphql

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, graphql, graphql-java, vue-apollo

I'm working on graphQL and spring boot project. The API works well using graphiQL but when trying to consume it using Apollo vueJS, it causes CORS origin error.

I'm using   @CrossOrigin annotation in ProductQuery class which implements GraphQLQueryResolver like  below:

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:8081")
public List<Product> getProducts(){return this.productService.findAll(); }
```

Here is the  error displayed on frontEnd project: 
[image: CORS origin error]

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

For local development you may need a `CorsFilter` bean to enable your local origin:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class LocalCorsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/graphql/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to start the application with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`.

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring Boot 2.7.0 there are configuration properties for CORS with GraphQL:

```
spring:
  graphql:
    cors:
      allow-credentials: true
      allowed-origins:
        - http://localhost:3000
```

See [GraphQlCorsProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlCorsProperties.java) for further properties.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the solution explained in the official [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

My version of a configurer bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/graphql/**")
                    .allowedOrigins(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                    .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                    .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to add this in your application properties `graphql.servlet.corsEnabled: true` after that your server response header will have the CORS properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution is a "remake" of whipper slapper's answer. The docs are saying, that you need to add the `corsConfigurer`-`@Bean` to your Application Class. This is, what it looks like in Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun corsConfigurer(): WebMvcConfigurer {
    return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
        override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
            registry.addMapping("/graphql/**")
                .allowedOrigins(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
        }
    }
}
```